# We’re trying to delete all data about Banana Republic from our stats database

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

We’re trying to delete all rows that have data for Account name= Banana Republic....

So far we have:

```
Delete Account_T
From Account_T 
Join Program_T
Where Account_T.AccountName = Program_T.AccountName 
And AccountName = ‘Banana Republic’
```

Here are the tables:

```
create table Program_T
    (AccountName varchar(150) not null unique,
    ProgramID int not null,
    Revenue int,
    Advocates int,
    Shares int,
    Conversions int,
    Impressions int,
    LaunchDate date,
    CSMID int not null,
    constraint Program_PK primary key (AccountName, CSMID),
    constraint Program_FK1 foreign key (AccountName) references Account_T(AccountName),
    constraint Program_FK2 foreign key (CSMID) references CSM_T(CSMID));
```

and Account_T table:

```
create table Account_T
    (AccountName varchar(150) not null unique,
    Health varchar(10) not null,
    EcommercePlatform varchar(50),
    CSMID int not null,
    Industry varchar(50),
    Amount int not null,
    constraint Accounts_PK primary key (AccountName),
    constraint Accounts_FK foreign key (CSMID) references CSM_T(CSMID));
```

Comment: You are trying yes, but what is your problem ? Syntax error ? Bad query ? If you are working on a delete statement, NEVER use DELETE, just comment the SELECT clause before a bad delete happens.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Republic’' at line 5

Comment: Try to replace `‘Banana Republic’` with `'Banana Republic'` (see change in quote symbol).

Comment: Well, I have encounter something like this before. It seems like copying the query to and from Microfost Word will change the backquote type to an unacceptable character. Have to revise the backquote again when copying from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do two `delete`s?

```
delete a from Account_T a
    where AccountName = 'Banana Republic';

delete p from Program_T p
    where AccountName = 'Banana Republic';
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the bad character before and after `Banana Republic`.

Write the query like this :

```
DELETE Account_T
FROM Account_T AS A
JOIN Program_T AS P
    ON A.AccountName = P.AccountName
Where A.AccountName = 'Banana Republic'
```

I wrote `DELETE`, but don't forget to always test with a `SELECT` first !

Use the `ON` clause with your JOIN instead of the jointure condition in the `WHERE`, its important to respect this.

Comment: *"Use the ON clause with your JOIN instead of the jointure condition in the WHERE, its important to respect this."* Yes but the MySQL optimizer knows that `JOIN Program_T AS P
Where A.AccountName = P.AccountName AND A.AccountName = 'Banana Republic'` and `ON A.AccountName = P.AccountName
Where A.AccountName = 'Banana Republic'` are one and the same things see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tL9dcMPddJiRc6kYY4Akku/0)   and notice the sql rewrites are the same in MySQL.

Comment: Ho yes, I know that the query plan are the same. Same as `FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE ...` . It's just a syntax to respect. Because this one is deprecated since 1986

Comment: Yes it should not be the `ON` clause is required by SQL standards MySQL accepts it. *"Same as FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE ... . It's just a syntax to respect. Because this one is deprecated since 1986 "* No it's never been deprecated by anny SQL standard atleast it's still in the SQL 2003 standards (don't have newer ones) `<query specification> ::=    SELECT [ <set quantifier> ] <select list> <table expression>
<select list> ::=    <asterisk>  | <select sublist> [ { <comma> <select sublist> }... ]`, notice the `[ { <comma> <select sublist> }..` part the question is if you should use it or not..